# how to do service configuration on RHEL8

Tags: service, configuration, systemd, systemctl, rhel8

Tried scheduling service on rhel 8 as below --
cd /etc/systemd/system
created symbolic link to service
sudo ln -s /apps/xyz/abc.service /etc/systemd/system/abc.service
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 51 Sep 10 16:14 abc.service -> /apps/xyz/abc.service sudo systemctl start abc.service

Gives error : Failed to start abc.service: Unit abc.service not found.
cat abc.service command  works well and able to access service  from same location.  But when I run 'systemctl cat abc.service' gives error : no file found as abc.service
Why. Is systemctl not able to access this service?

journalctl -u abc.service , doesnot has any any entries.
systemctl list-unit-files gives unit file state bad

Same steps work well on RHEL7 and unit file state shows linked. Any ideas on how this can be resolved?